# How to convert an object to a string without adding a bunch of commas?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

I have this object that I want to convert to a string, but when I do its also adding all of the commas that iit had as an array. How can I remove those without turning it back into an array?
`",2,3,5,0,8,8,7,9,9,0,7,4,4,8,4,2,2,4,"`

Comment: You need to give us what object you initially had.

Comment: How are you converting the object to a string?

Comment: @FelixKling obj.toString();

Comment: If you actually have an array then you should do `arr.join('')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `replace` and `trim`

```js
const str = ",2,3,5,0,8,8,7,9,9,0,7,4,4,8,4,2,2,4,"

const res = str.replace(/,/g, " ").trim()

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Can't accept answer for another 9 minutes. I cant believe i forgot about .replace(), maybe I should take a break... anyways, in my case I cant have anything between my numbers so I just did (/,/g, "") and it works like a charm, thanks man! will accept the answer asap